# Failing to install ghost local install

Tags: node.js, web, ghost-blog

When i try to install ghost using the ghost local command i keep getting the following error:

> error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/gscan/-/gscan-3.5.4.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT                                                                    : no such file or directory, symlink 'test/fixtures/themes/030-assets/symlink/assets/foo.png' -> '/home//.cache/yarn/v6/npm-gscan-3.5.4                                                                    -b9214433b5e866d364e4997b32b2d2c8f5a5fef7-integrity/node_modules/gscan/test/fixtures/themes/030-assets/symlink/assets/mysymlink.png'"

I've tried different versions and node versions but I always get the same error, anyone came across this before? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are using yarn, try this below:

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install --network-concurrency 1
```

also if you still facing the error try to delete the yarn.lock file and reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I had the same error when building the theme, and cleaning yarn cache and removing node_modules fixed it (without deleting the lock file).
`yarn cache clean && rm -rf node_modules`